# How to calculate intersection in numpy.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume that:

numpy array A is

```
[[1,2,3,4]
 [8,4,4,4]]
```

numpy array B is

```
[[1,2,3,4]
 [5,2,4,7]]
```

the intersection is

```
[[1,2,3,4]]
```

**and the type is float64**, how to calculate intersection using the numpy?

my poor solution:

```
inter = []
for item in A.tolist():
    if item in B.tolist():
        inter.append(item)
inter = numpy.array(inter)
```

but i dont think this is a good solution,and i wonder the method make loss on precision?

Comment: Did you mean `if item in B.tolist():` ?

Comment: yes, it is item in B.tolist()